# Input() function in Python: How can I create an action out of user input?

Tags: python, list, input

I would like to know how to get a list related action out of user input. This would be my "solution" but it doesn´t work and just gives me back the user´s input.

```
oldList = ['1', '2']
newList = input('Which number should be included in the List?')
if newList == 1:
    oldList.append(1)
elif newList == 2:
    oldList.append(2)

print(oldList)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Answer (score 1):

The input by default will be in string format. So when you read input in `newList`, its value is : `'1'`. So the below code would work.

```
oldList = ['1', '2']
newList = input('Which number should be included in the List?') 
if newList == '1':     # and not 1
    oldList.append(1)
elif newList == '2':
    oldList.append(2)

print(oldList)
```

**Input :** `1`

**Output :**

```
Which number should be included in the List?
['1', '2', 1]
```

You could instead also try keeping your same comparison and just converting `newList` into int. That would work as well.

---

**NOTE :** The above code will append an integer to `oldList`. So, if you want to append string , you should change the code to `oldList.append(str(1))`.

One more thing, if you just want to append a number which user inputs, you can use this -

#### Short-hand Version :

```
oldList = ['1', '2']
oldList.append(int(input('Which number should be included in the List?')))
print(oldList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
oldList = ['1', '2']
newList = str(input('Which number should be included in the List?'))
if newList == str(1):
    oldList.append(str(1))
elif newList == str(2):
    oldList.append(str(2))

print(oldList)
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of why `str()` is necessary here? Remember, the goal of Stack Overflow isn't just to _show_ people the right answer, but help them _understand_ it. Take a look at @Abhishek's answer—it's an excellent example of how to address these types of questions.

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function returns string variables, not numbers so instead of this:

```
if newList==1:
 oldList.append(1)
```

use:

```
if newList=='1':
 oldList.append('1')
```

However, your code would be cleaner if you directly appended the input like this:

```
oldList.append(input('Which number should be included in the List?'))
```

-Edit: if you want to make sure that you are only storing numbers you could use the following code as well:

```
try:
 oldList.append(int(input('Which number should be included in the List?'))
except:
 print("That wasn't a number!")
```